# Playing a video javascript blob within Cordova / Phonegap on IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, html5-video

I'm playing to play a video encoded as a blob on IOS 7 within the Cordova application wrapper. I pull the video from a local datastore as a base64 encoded string, and then turn it back into a Uint8Array. From there use createObjectURL to get a blob / file URI, and use it as the source for the  tag. Here's the code. I used the same approach to pull a PDF from the datastore and render it using PDF.js, but

```
// ignore the first 12 bytes of the base64EncodedVideo
var base64EncodedVideo = collateral.body.substring(12);
var array= str_to_ab(b64_to_utf8(base64EncodedVideo));
var blob = new Blob([array.buffer], {type: 'video/mp4'});
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
$j("#videoContent").prop("src", url);
$j.mobile.changePage('#videoPage', {changeHash: true});
```

....

```
function str_to_ab(str) { 
    var bufView = new Uint8Array(str.length);
    for (var i=0; i< str.length; i++) {
        bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bufView;
}

function b64_to_utf8( str ) {
    return (window.atob(str));
}
```

I've confirmed that the object is coming out of the datastore correctly and can be played as a file (once base64 encoding is removed etc).

I've also tried pass the base64 encoded string as using a Data URI, but that doesn't work either on IOS.

Any thoughts or suggestions ?

Comment: Potentially related Cordova issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6079